# Use case for Future.cancel(false)?

Tags: java, concurrency, future

In what situation would one want to pass `false` for the `mayInterruptIfRunning` parameter to `Future.cancel()`?

If I understand correctly, if you pass `false` and the task is cancelled but the thread is *not* interrupted, the result (or `ExecutionException`) will never be accessible because the task is still marked as cancelled (i.e. `isCancelled()` returns `true` and `get()` throws `CancellationException`.)

Other possible situations are:

- The `Runnable` or `Callable` implementation does not check for interrupts and will run to completion even if you do interrupt it (here the interrupt makes no difference)
- The task already completed before you called `cancel()` (again the interrupt makes no difference)
- The task needs to perform some cleanup before it exits (a well-written implementation will use `try ... finally` for this.)
- The task cannot terminate immediately and must continue to perform operations that would be affected by interrupts, e.g. blocking I/O (in this case you should probably not call `cancel` at all)

So when/why would you cancel a task without interrupting it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're afraid interrupting the task's execution might leave things in a bad state, and you simply want to mark it as canceled so that users of the `Future` will be aware of it (e.g. they should know the statistics requested weren't performed on time).

Writing threaded code that handles interrupts correctly is not trivial at all, and so one might simply prefer to avoid it.

Some information can be found [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue160.html), [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) and of course in the great book [Concurrent Programming in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310090) (by the guy who originally wrote `java.util.concurrent`).

Comment: Your first statement isn't quite right.  If the task is running or complete than cancel(false) doesn't mark it as cancelled.

Answer (score 22):

tl;dr; `Future.cancel(false)` is only useful to avoid starting tasks that hadn't already been started.

There are two important things to understand regarding concurrency and cancellation.

The first is that in Java cancellation is purely cooperative.  Java signals the cancellation request by having blocking methods throw InterruptedExcetions and by setting a flag on the Thread.  The task implementation is responsible for noticing the cancellation request AND cancelling itself.  Brian Goetz explains interruption in his post [Dealing with InterruptedException](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html).  Not all task implementations will correctly handle interruption.

The second thing to point out is that the Future object is a placeholder for the results from a task to be executed in the future.  If you don't have alot of threads running it is possible that the task starts executing right away but its also possible that all the threads are already being used and the task has to wait.  Just because you have a reference to a Future object that doesn't mean that the corresponding task has actually started running.  Its sort of like a reservation.

You have a Future object but the task could be in one of the following states:

1. Waiting.  For example it might be in a queue of other tasks waiting for processor time.
2. Running.
3. Completed.

If your task is in the first state "Waiting" then both `Future.cancel(true)` and `Future.cancel(false)` will mark the future as cancelled.  The task remains in the queue of tasks to execute but when the executor gets to the task it notices the cancelled flag and skips it.

If your task is in the third state "Completed" than both `Future.cancel(true)` and `Future.cancel(false)` return false and don't do anything.  Which makes sense because they are already done and there isn't a way to undo them.

The `mayInterruptIfRunning` flag is only important if your task is in the second state "Running".

If your task is running and `mayInterruptIfRunning` is false then the executor doesn't do anything and allows the task to complete.

If your task is running and `mayInterruptIfRunning` is true then the executor will interrupt the task.  But remember the bit about cooperative cancellation - for the interruption to work the task has to have been implemented to handle cancellation.

Summary:

`Future.cancel(true)` is appropriate when:

1. The Future represents a long running task that is known to have been implemented to handle interruption.

`Future.cancel(false)` would be correct:

1. The task implementation cannot handle being interrupted.
2. Its unknown if the task implementation supports cancellation.
3. You are willing to wait for already started tasks to complete.

Comment: Nice round up.  It's unfortunate we can't distinguish whether it was Waiting or Running from the return value of `cancel()`.

Comment: @antak I once needed something like that and extended FutureTask.  In the ctor you wrap the Callable parameter with your own callable that sets a wasStarted flag before calling into the original callable.call()

Comment: Yeah, although one will need to take care with synchronization as there's a critical section between the executor committing to start the task and our code setting `wasStarted`.

Comment: @antak Not really. You're wrapping the original callable with your own.  When your callable gets called the executor has already given you a thread to execute on.  The implementation sets the flag and calls into the original callable.  Nothing can get in-between.  The original callable might check for interruption or cancellation and immediately exit but the wasStarted flag will still be valid. The callable was started.

Comment: Yes, but you call `cancel(...)` and it returns `true`.  You don't know whether it was Waiting or Running so you look at `wasStarted` and it's `false`.  That still doesn't rule out "Running" (i.e. the task won't run / hasn't already run) as you could be in the critical section, or the variable may simply not be propagated (if it's not `volatile`).  Both `cancel(false)` and `cancel(true)` will require a specific kind of synchronization to determine *absolutely* if the original callable was started or will never be started.

Comment: "If your task is running and mayInterruptIfRunning is true then the executor will interrupt the **task**." should be "If your task is running and mayInterruptIfRunning is true then the executor will interrupt **the thread executing this task**.". From [Future (Java SE 10 & JDK 10 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean))

Answer (score 1):

I have a use case that might be interesting to you:  I have a single thread that is executing a set of scheduled tasks.  One of the tasks may be rescheduled by either itself or another task.

To do this, I use `Future.cancel(false)` on the existing copy in the queue, and then schedule the task for the new time.

If this code is called from the scheduled task itself, the cancel operation will be a no-op, and the task will be scheduled to run again in the future.  If the code is called from another context, the upcoming task hasn't started execution yet, so it will be canceled, and replaced with a task scheduled for the new time.